# Objective-C proper use of blocks with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block, objective-c-blocks

I know this question has been asked before, but non of the solutions solve my problem, so I'm asking this again. I am trying to call a method on self as the result of a callback through a  block. I'm getting the following error:

**Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead a retain cycle**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.webClient.completionHandler = ^{
      [self populateData];
   };
}
```

I tried doing something like the code below, and I'm still getting the same warning.
What's the solution?

```
__weak id myself = self;
[myself populateData];
```

Comment: Are you putting the __weak line inside the block? If so it needs to be before the line where you set the completion handler/define the block.

Comment: yes right before [self populateData]

Comment: Is there a cleaner weay to be able to do everything inside the block?

Comment: What if you change the `self.webClient...` to just `webClient...`?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use a property to access `webClient` or not. `webClient` is presumably a strong ivar (i.e. retained by self), so if `self` retains `webClient` and `webClient` retains the block, and the block retains `self`, you have a retain cycle.

Comment: UIAdam, to clarify, are you saying that accessing an ivar in a block causes the block to retain `self`?

Comment: Well, I edited my last comment to be more relevant to @jjv360's comment, but yes if you access an ivar in a block, the block will retain self. That is not exactly the issue in this case since you are directly using `self` in the block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   __weak id weakSelf = self;
   self.webClient.completionHandler = ^{
      [weakSelf populateData];
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIAdam gave the correct answer, but it's worth understanding why it is correct.

First, why did you get the warning?

self has a strong reference to webClient. webClient has a strong reference to completionHandler. completionHandler has a strong reference to self. So if all other references in your program go away, there is still a strong reference to each item in this cycle, so they can never be deallocated.

The attempt of writing

```
__weak id myself = self;
[myself populateData];
```

doesn't work of course. The block still references self because it is assigning it to myself. So no difference here.

UIAdam's solution of writing

__weak id weakSelf = self;
   self.webClient.completionHandler = ^{
      [weakSelf populateData];
   };

means that weakSelf is a weak reference, and the block only contains a weak reference to self. So if all other strong references to self is gone, there's only a weak reference left. A weak reference doesn't keep self alive, so self gets deallocated.

Now what if that happens, but something else had a strong reference to webClient and your block is called? weakSelf is a weak reference, and weak references are set to nil when the object is deallocated. So you have to be prepared that weakSelf is nil when your block gets called. It is actually better to write

```
id strongSelf = weakSelf;
[strongSelf populatedData];
```

inside the block: strongSelf might be set to nil, or it will be set to self. But since it is a strong reference, it will stay non-nil until the block has finished. If it was not nil to start with.

Comment: "It is actually better to write" In this case there is no difference.